# Windows Phone 8.1 HubApp + HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, html-agility-pack

I know that using HAP in windows phone apps is very problematic, but I very need to. So the problem is that when I add System.Xml.XPath from silverlight 5 or 4 I get "Xaml Internal Error error WMC9999". It's got to be noticed that the version of HAP is 1.4.6 but not 1.4.9 (tha latest one), because it cannot be installed from NuGet (just doesn't add reference) and I've found no links to download it manually.
In old windows phone 8 silverlight app everything worked great.
Please, help.

Comment: Did you tried to add the reference manually from dll?

Comment: Yes, I added HAP 1.4.6 for Silverlight 5 and system.xml.xpath manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [HtmlAgilityPack-PCL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack-PCL/) nuget package with Windows Phone 8.1 XAML apps, it works fine with no need to add any references manually.

Comment: It's not the full version of HAP, but it does work. But I went another way: I took dll from winrt45 folder of HAP 1.4.6. It works same as HAP-PCL, I suppose. The biggest disadvantage is that there is no XPath support in winrt45 and PCL versions. So I had to change all my XPath string queries to linq queries and certainly I dislike such approach, but there is no another way out, I suppose.